# Isomorphisms in rotation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\rho : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ denote rotation around $0$ over $\dfrac{2 \pi}{3}$. Set $f = \rho - \text{id}$ and $g = \rho + 2 \cdot \text{id}$. We have previously shown that $$\rho((x,y)) = (x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta, x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta)$$
>
> 1. Show $ f \circ g = g \circ f = 3 \cdot \text{id}$.
> 2. Conclude $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms

An isomorphism is a map $f$ which satisfies:

- $f$ is bijective
- preserves structure (like a linear transformation does)

For the second part I was a little bit more powerless, as I don't really understand how the first part ties in with the second part, or how the result $ f \circ g = g \circ f = 3 \cdot \text{id}$ (which I've proven with the help of a comment here) helps you conclude $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: There is a subtle error in your formula for $f$ and $g$. That should $\sqrt 3 x$ and $\sqrt 3 y$, not $\sqrt{3x}$ and $\sqrt{3y}$. Whether this error was in your work and in what you provided wolfram alpha, or just in your write-up here, I don't know.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I actually think that solves it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find out that $f$ and $g$ are linear transformations, so they preserve the structure.

A linear transformation $h_1$ is an isomorphism if and only if there exists a linear transformation $h_2$ such that $h_1\circ h_2=h_2\circ h_1=id$. 
Can you figure out them in $f\circ g=g\circ f=3\cdot id$?

Or you can prove it by showing the following 2 claims, where $f,g$ are two maps:

If $f\circ g$ is injective, then $g$ is injective.

If $f\circ g$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the second part. The statement "A linear transformation $h_1$ is an isomorphism if and only if.." is not intuitive to me, I haven't encountered it anywhere else.

Comment: For the only if part, you know $h_1$ is an isomorphism, what's a natural way to find a $h_2$ satisfying the property? For the if part, you could try to prove the two claims first and then to show it.

Comment: A natural $h_2$? The inverse of $h_1$, maybe?

Comment: @Kamaljit Yes, you are right. It remains to check its inverse is a linear transformation.

Comment: So the "linear transformation" $h_2$ is basically the inverse? So this is basically another way of saying that a function is bijective iff it has an inverse? So would $f \circ \dfrac{g}{3} = g \circ \dfrac{f}{3} = \text{id}$?

Comment: @Kamaljit Yes, you are right. A bijective map has an inverse as a map. And fortunately, the inverse map of a bijective linear transformation is still a linear transformation in your example.